# Html field incrementer breaks if field is edited by user

Tags: javascript, html

Below I have code that is problematic to me. The purpose of it is to increment "input class=qty". This works great unless the user puts in their own number then decides they want to return to using the incremental buttons. My impression is that I can no longer reference the value once the field is edited, but I'm unsure as to what the cause is or a proper solution. Help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function qtyPlus(fieldId){
    var curVal = parseInt(document.getElementById(fieldId).value);

    if(isNaN(curVal)) {
        document.getElementById(fieldId).setAttribute('value', 0); 
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(fieldId).setAttribute('value', curVal+1);
    }
}

function qtyMinus(fieldId) {
    var curVal = parseInt(document.getElementById(fieldId).value);

    if(isNaN(curVal)) {
        document.getElementById(fieldId).setAttribute('value', 0);
    }
    else {
        if(curVal != 0) {
            document.getElementById(fieldId).setAttribute('value', curVal-1);
        }
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type='button' value='-' onclick='qtyMinus("numOfAttendees")' class='qtyminus' >       
<input type='text' value='0' class='qty' id='numOfAttendees' >
<input type='button' value='+' onclick='qtyPlus("numOfAttendees")' class='qtyplus' >

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your js for:

```
function qtyPlus(fieldId){
    var curVal = parseInt(document.getElementById(fieldId).value);

    if(isNaN(curVal)) {
        document.getElementById(fieldId).value = 0; 
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(fieldId).value = curVal+1;
    }
}

function qtyMinus(fieldId) {
    var curVal = parseInt(document.getElementById(fieldId).value);

    if(isNaN(curVal)) {
        document.getElementById(fieldId).value = 0;
    }
    else {
        if(curVal != 0) {
            document.getElementById(fieldId).value = curVal-1;
        }
    }
}
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/7dhjT/